# Can JM20339 Driver for Windows 98 be installed in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, external-hard-drive, windows-98

I have an old SATA adaptor for a external hard disk drive. It uses the chip JMicro JM20339. I searched all day for a Windows 7 driver, but it seems that it doesn't exist.

The only one I found was a Windows 98 driver with these files:

- JMUsbMon.exe
- JMUsbSto.inf
- JMUsbSto.sys
- JMUSPDR.pdr
- Setup.exe

When I run Setup.exe using "Compatibility mode" for Windows 98, and "Run as administrator" nothing happens. What can I do to install these drivers?

Comment: It's likely you're SOL -- the device driver model has probably changed too much from Windows 98 to Windows 7. I'm assuming that at least the architecture is correct, x86 Win98 driver and you're on x86 Win7. You could try locating the device in device manager and right click => update driver (or something similarly worded) and browsing to the folder that contains the .inf file.

Comment: I tryed that too... I can't find the device in "Device manager" even. I tryed to install the INF using "Right Click > Install" but I got this message: "the inf file you selected does not support this method of installation"

Comment: It sounds like you have another problem to solve before you worry about the driver: making your computer recognise the device.

Comment: I think that this device isn't plug and play, and that's why I need to install the drivers first...

Comment: Windows 98 and Windows 7 are completely unrelated OSes. Windows 98 is Windows, while Windows 7 is Windows NT. There is no way a driver for one would work on the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as ta.speot.is says, the problem was in the connection. After many tries, the problem was the cable. I was using the cable that comes with the external hard disk case, an USB cable 2.0 with two ports to connect to the PC. Now, I'm using a USB 3.0 cable and problem solved.

Thanks,

Comment: PS. the drivers weren't needed. Windows 7 recognize the external hard disk automatically.